# Softmax regression cost function code

Tags: machine-learning, multilabel-classification, scipy, softmax, sparse

I really do not understand what does this code do

`M = sparse.coo_matrix(([1]*n, (Y, range(n))), shape=(k,n)).toarray()`

[image: Cost function]
The code is related to calculating the sparse function in this equation, but I am really confused and I do not know how it iterates through it and what is:
1- sparse.coo_matrix
2- (Y, range(n)))
3-shape=(k,n)).toarray()
??

Also, What exactly does this term means in the equation and how to interpret it into code:[image]

Thank you , and please forgive my poor English.

Answer (score 2):

It's a loss function applied to a regression with l2 penalty on the parameters.
The first square brackets can be interpreted in the following way:

- $ - \frac{1}{n} $ has the minus because it wants to minimize.
- $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$ means for each data point.
- $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} $ means for each class.
- $y_i == j$ means that the fraction after this term is calculated only for true class. This check makes sense because y true is an OHE vector like [0, 0, 1], therefore you want to evaluate only the predicted probability associated with the true class. Take into account softmax function: if you increase the probability of a single output in output in the softmax you are implicitly reducing the probabilities of the other outputs.
- the log division is the softmax function.
- $ + \frac{\lambda}{2} \dots $ is a l2 regularization term on the model parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much Mikedev for your help, would you please explain the attached code elements too ? and what does OHE stand for? and does the result of y_i == j is multiplied by the log function next to it ? thanks again I really appreciate your help

Comment: OHE = one hot encoding. $y_i$ is the label of ith row of the dataset like 3, 4 etc. (a discrete number). Therefore y_i == j means that you evaluate in the loss function only the jth output of the model that corresponds the probability of class j

Comment: Thank you very much Mikedev, would you please explain the attached code as well ?